# Same random using GLM

Tags: opengl, math, glm-math

I'm using GLM for the maths in my openGL videogame. The case is, I'm using the following statement to generate a random double:

```
glm::linearRand(min, max);
```

And yes, it generates a random number, but the problem is that this number is always the same if I close the game and open it again. It will always generate the same order of randoms. Is this normal? Any way to change this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize linearRand with srand since it uses the C standard library rand internally. Use time or some other variable number with srand so you get different results each time.

Comment: How can I initialize lineRand with the srand? Thanks

Comment: Simple set `srand` based on time such as `srand (time(NULL));` ( See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/ for full example).